# Pipe, filtering and Select () in R - order of code

Tags: r, select, filter, pipe

I was ask to do the below question from a exercise:

> Create a new data frame from the surveys data that meets the following criteria: contains only the species_id column and a new column called hindfoot_cm containing the hindfoot_length values converted to centimeters. In this hindfoot_cm column, there are no NAs and all values are less than 3.

then was shown the solution as below codes

```
surveys_hindfoot_cm <- surveys %>% # 1
   filter(!is.na(hindfoot_length)) %>% # 2
   mutate(hindfoot_cm = hindfoot_length / 10) %>% # 3
   filter(hindfoot_cm < 3) %>% # 4
   select(species_id, hindfoot_cm) # 5
```

I don't understand the last bit select(). Why is that function put in the last line but not the beginning? Plus, why it the **hindfoot_length** column not selected and its the **hindfoot_cm** selected instead?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dplyr::select()` call on line 5 could have been swapped with line 4 but not earlier. The `hindfoot_cm` column didn't exist until the `dplyr::mutate()` call on line 3.

The `hindfoot_cm` column is selected because that's what the question stipulates.